# WooCommerce Product Title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Where is the page title "blog" coming from? I would just like it to display the shop title.

https://www.sunfinityre.com/shop/hats/hat-with-logo/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is coming from your theme.  The HTML output is...

```
</div>
 </div></header>


<div id="page-title">
    <h1>BLOG</h1>
    <p><span><a href="/">Home</a></span> / <span><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></span></p>
</div>



</div> <!-- closing for page-header bg -->
```

You may want to search your theme for `closing for page-header bg` or `div id="page-title"` perhaps and see if you can find the `<h1>` output anywhere in there as that may give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="page-title">
<h1>BLOG</h1>
<p><span><a href="/">Home</a></span> / <span><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></span></p>
```

this is the code of your blog title when you inspect elements.. to do this you need to hide it in your css:

```css
body.single-product #page-title{display:none;}
```